using sed to replace multiline pattern by contents of file
I have a file certs.txtcontaining sections with multiline patterns such as
  CAChain = [IIH1zCCBr+gAwIBAgISBPW9KTc3ma4BJ5Dwjsap3vuSMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMDMxCzAJ
BgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQwwCgYDVQQDEwNSMTEwHhcNMjQw
OTE4MDE0MjE5WhcNMjQxMjE3MDE0MjE4WjAWMRQwEgYDVQQDEwt3ZXJrd2VsdC5kZTCCASIw
DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJ09pgyz+iRHeuckR92soEwaN7/WzGIigdQV
...
...
x3bn
];

Each section can be identified by sed "s/= \[[^\]]*\];/= [/"  but my search doesn't cross lines.
Aim is to replace
CAChain = [IIH1zCCBr+gAwIBAgISBPW9KTc3ma4BJ5Dwjsap3vuSMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMDMxCzAJ
BgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQwwCgYDVQQDEwNSMTEwHhcNMjQw
OTE4MDE0MjE5WhcNMjQxMjE3MDE0MjE4WjAWMRQwEgYDVQQDEwt3ZXJrd2VsdC5kZTCCASIw
DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJ09pgyz+iRHeuckR92soEwaN7/WzGIigdQV
...
...
x3bn];


by
CAChain = [ <contents of file> 
];


I must admit that I never knew about that feature to accept an answer.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E '/= \[/{:a;N;/\];/!ba
        s/(= \[).*(\];)/\1$(cat replacementFile)\2/
        s/.*/echo "&"/e}' file

Search for the start of a section then gather up further lines until the end of the section.
Using the substitution command replace inside the square brackets with a shell command to cat the entire replacement file.
Using the substitution command and the e flag replace the entire contents of the pattern space by an echo command which when evaluated will output the required result.

Consider using awk instead of sed for anything more complicated than a simple s/old/new/, e.g. using GNU awk for mult-char RS and the 3rd arg to match():
$ cat file
foo
bar


$ awk -v RS='\n$' '
    NR==FNR { new=$0; next }
    match($0, /(.*= \[)[^]]+(];.*)/ , a) {
        $0 = a[1] new a[2] }
    }
1' file certs.txt
CAChain = [foo
bar];

I see from your now-deleted answer that you have several additional transformations you also need to make on your input. You will find doing all of that vastly clearer, simpler, more robust, and more efficient with an awk script than a pile of sed commands, subprocesses, and pipelines as you show in that answer.

I gave you a +1. OTOH, and although awk and perl and python all might do the job, I prefer a sheer sed solution.

That's fine but it's important to learn at some point when to use a hammer and when to use a screwdriver based on the job at hand. Hopefully you understand that the other answer you currently have isn't a "sheer sed" solution, it's using a mixture of sed, bash, cat, and echo to solve your problem.
